# Best way to transpose between column major and row major order with SSE

Tags: matrix, x86, transpose, sse, intrinsics

Let's say we have this 2d (3,4) array stored in row major order:

```
0 1  2  3 | 4 5  6  7 | 8 9 10 11
```

My goal is to change it to column major order:

```
0 4 8 | 1 5 9 | 2 6 10 | 3 7 11
```

-> What is the fastest way to do that?

What I tried:

- If the matrix is symmetric (NxN) I used Intel's _MM_TRANSPOSE4_PS.
- If the matrix is not symmetric (MxN, M!=N):  I developed a transpose function based on Intel's instruction sets provided here: https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/# 
  It is showing good results but once the array is really big (e.g. 120k*120k*complex64) the pressure on PORT5 increases significantly and the performance is dramatically low as described here in chapter 14-11 https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/9e/bc/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.pdf
- Also the idea to use less shuffles didn't really help. Moving shuffles to the load PORTS 2,3 neither.
- Gather and scatter operations are super slow and therefore no option

Is there any trick I don't know about :D

Comment: Your example is a tiny matrix that fits in a few SIMD registers.  But it sounds like your real question is for large matrices that don't fit in cache.  Often you can avoid transposing them, e.g. the most efficient way to do a matmul isn't to transpose one matrix first.  Instead take advantage of reading 4 or 8 columns at once.

Comment: Or if you do need to transpose, cache-block aka tile your loops so your making use of all the data in a cache line after touching it.  A sub-rectangle of a matrix involves several full cache lines.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! The example was just for illustration. How would you perform a good caching? I was dividing the big matrix into blocks and then cached the blocks.